# What is ‘dew’ as described in scripture and what is the application of this to our lives?

Tags: psalms, zechariah

What is the dew from heaven?

> Zechariah 8:12 - For there shall be a sowing of peace. The vine shall
> give its fruit, and the ground shall give its produce, and the heavens
> shall give their dew. And I will cause the remnant of this people to
> possess all these things.

Is this the same dew that falls on Zion?

> Psalms 133:3 - It is like the dew of Hermon, which falls on the
> mountains of Zion! For there the LORD has commanded the blessing, life
> forevermore.

From my understanding dew is also considered a ‘covering’. Is this right?

Comment: a metaphor for rain

Comment: Not even a metaphor. Rain is literally dew of heaven as opposed to the dew of the earth

Answer (score 1):

Meteorologically – “God give you the dew of heaven” – Literally speaking, dew assures agricultural productivity thus representing material prosperity. This is used many times in scripture as representing a source of blessing as in Genesis 27:27-29.

> And he came near and kissed him; and he smelled the smell of his
> clothing, and blessed him and said: ‘Surely, the smell of my son is
> like the smell of a field which the LORD has blessed. Therefore, may
> God give you of the dew of heaven, of the fatness of the earth, and
> plenty of grain and wine. Let peoples serve you, and nations bow down to you. Be master over your brethren and let your mother’s sons bow
> down to you. Cursed be everyone who curses you and blessed be those
> who bless you!’”

Answer (score 0):

Talam (טַלָּם) from [Zechariah 8:12] is possessive form of Tal(טַל):"Dew".

Although "Tal (טַל)" is earthly produce generated after YHVH only [Jeremiah 14:22] permits the world's GeShamayim(גְּשָׁמִים):"rains",

Spoken Words are (כַּ-טַּל) "like-Dew" (Deuteronomy 32:2) covering of vital nourishment.

Dew relates to spiritual Safety as symbolic protection over Israel in [Deuteronomy 33:28]

"Yisrael dwells in safety, untroubled is Yaaqov’s abode, in a land of grain and wine - under Heaven's dripping טָל Dew." ( וַיִּשְׁכֹּן יִשְׂרָאֵל בֶּטַח בָּדָד עֵין יַֽעֲקֹ֔ב אֶל־אֶ֖רֶץ דָּגָן וְתִירוֹשׁ אַף־שָׁמָיו יַעַרְפוּ טָֽל )

**Dew of Heaven טַּל הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם** from YHVH is wished upon יַעֲקֹב Yaaqov in [Genesis 27:28] as a blessing to עֵשָׂו Esav by his father יִצְחָק Yitschaq **to ensure prosperity**.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Clarke thought the dew of heaven meant God's blessings.

> "For the seed shall be prosperous — Ye shall be a holy and peaceable people; and God will pour down his blessing on yourselves, your fields, and your vineyards."  (Source:  [Clarke's](https://studylight.org/commentaries/eng/acc/zechariah-8.html)

Clarke on Psa. 133:3 -

> "see Deuteronomy 4:48: "Mount Sion, which is Hermon." On this mountain the dew is very copious. Mr. Maundrell says that "with this dew, even in dry weather, their tents were as wet as if it had rained the whole night." This seems to show the strength of the comparison.

> For there — Where this unity is.

> The Lord commanded the blessing — That is, an everlasting life. There he pours out his blessings, and gives a long and happy life."  (Source: [Clarke's](https://studylight.org/commentaries/eng/acc/psalms-133.html)

But, there is another point, as all of God's blessings come from abiding in His word.  The unity and communion of the remnant would be nothing if they were not abiding with God, and obeying the commands.  In Deu. 32:1-2, God's word drops as the rain.

> "*`Give ear, O heavens, and I speak; And thou dost hear, O earth, sayings of my mouth! 2 Drop as rain doth My doctrine; Flow as dew doth My sayings; As storms on the tender grass, And as showers on the herb,"*  (YLT)

The source of the dew of the heavens is God, and the dew is His word. Our blessings come from abiding in His word.

Answer (score 0):

Though dew is the same everywhere, how much it is valued depends on the climate where it forms. The biblical references to dew consistently present it as a blessing and reflect the belief that dew is a vital resource for plants and thus for life itself. To understand its significance in the area of the Eastern Mediterranean, it may help to learn about the role of dew in the ecology of arid and semi-arid climates.

Although the moisture that it provides to the roots of plants is minimal, dew plays a vital role in the survival and growth of plants in arid climates. For one, dew helps plants regulate their internal moisture and thus helps to prevent wilting ([source](https://sustainable-secure-food-blog.com/2022/08/07/does-dew-provide-water-to-plants/)). For another, it helps to activate photosynthesis, the process by which plants make their own nutrients.

> From "Dual nature of dew: Researcher measures the effect of dew on
> desert plants" [Science Daily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/09/100928122608.htm)
>
> According to Prof. Alpert, plants in a semi-arid zone close these
> stomatic openings in the midday as a defence mechanism, to avoid
> losing moisture, or in other words water, when the weather is at its
> driest. When this happens, photosynthesis and plant growth cannot take
> place. For these reasons, the early-morning hours -- and not those of
> midday -- are the period of maximum growth for plants in the Eastern
> Mediterranean region, Prof. Alpert says. And it's all due to the dew.
> "In the early morning, dew surrounds the leaves of a plant with
> moisture, and the plant does not close its stomata. Therefore, it can
> grow." … Despite its negative reputation in other climates, dew has
> been idealized in the Eastern Mediterranean for its ability to help
> fruits and vegetables grow in a dry and inhospitable region.

Dew plays an essential role in creating the right conditions for plants to grow in arid environments. Beyond the science, dew has other characteristics that make it particularly apt for spiritual application. There is a mystery surrounding its origin. Dew seemingly comes from the heavens. Quietly, almost imperceptibly, it nurtures plants and life. Literally, the blessing of dew is a blessing for a good crop/harvest. Metaphorically, dew is symbolic of God’s spirit and grace, without which we would be unable to thrive and grow in the spiritual desert of this world.

> I will be like the dew to Israel; He will blossom like the lily, And
> he will take root like the cedars of Lebanon. - Hos 14:5